# Angular2 using import work on window but not work on linux

Tags: angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { User } from './../../class/User';
```

I get this

```
ERROR in ./src/app/service/user_service/user.service.ts
(4,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module './../../class/User'.
```

How can I use ng2 library for acceptable for `./../../class/User` window and linux

Comment: Is your `User.ts` file actually named with an uppercase `U`?

Comment: user.ts name like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux file systems are usually case sensitive.

An import like

```
import { User } from './../../class/User';
```

expects a file

```
User.ts
```

A file

```
user.ts
```

won't be found because the name doesn't match. 
Windows doesn't care about upper/lower-case but Linux does.